# Отступы вокруг элемента

Tags: html, css

Добавил на пустую страницу блок размером 400х400, нужно чтобы его начало координат было с самого угла, но он вокруг себя делает отступы как на скрине. Код предоставляю

```
   <style>
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   </style>
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background: black"></div>
```

[image: Отступ сверху, слева и снизу]

Answer (score 1):

Либо для установки нулевых значений отступов для всех элементов

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис `css`:

```
selector {
    attribute: value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если прям как на картинке, т.е. отступы везде кроме правой части, то вот так

Для **внешних** отступов:

```
.block {
    margin: 10px;    /*   Отступы везде.. */
    margin-right: 0; /* ..кроме правой части */
}
```

Для **внутренних** отступов:

```
.block {
    padding: 10px;    /*   Отступы везде.. */
    padding-right: 0; /* ..кроме правой части */
}
```

---

Сразу фикс, чтобы `.block` не вылезал за грани:

```
.block {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);  /* По ширине у нас 1 отступ = 10px */
    height: calc(100% - 20px); /* А по высоте 2 отступа = 20px */
}
```